# Make asp label invisible using timer

Tags: asp.net, timer, label, visible

i have to show a label indicating success of insertion of data. The label should disappear automatically after 5 seconds how can i achieve this??

```
 <html>
 <head id="Head1" runat="server">
 <title>Test Visibility</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#<%= lblError.ClientID%>').hide();
    }, 100); // <-- time in milliseconds
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

<asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery for this.

Call a function and it will hide it after a particular duration.

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $('#labelId').hide();
}, 1000); // <-- time in milliseconds
```

Suppose you have a label

```
  <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

So you can use it as follows

```
  setTimeout(function() {
   $('#<%= lblResult.ClientId%>').hide();
}, 1000); // <-- time in milliseconds
```

and in document.ready call it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       setTimeout(function() {
   $('#<%= lblResult.ClientId%>').hide();
}, 1000); // <-- time in milliseconds
});
```

Comment: Where i will call this functioin??

Comment: There is a spelling mistake `ClientID` the `d` is small and it should be in caps

Comment: label controls are rendered as span .can you update your code to reflect what and how you have implemented the changes suggested by @shekhar

Comment: @Ratna `jquery` `hide` method is independent it matter only if you are fetching the text. In that case `val()` will not work.

Comment: yes i can see that i ment that the function should be called by called using register.startup script after value has been given to label instead of document.load.

Comment: @Ratna it doesn't required to write on `register.startup` because my understanding suggests that the label will be hidden all the time and at the time of update he will show the label and in that case it is not required.

Comment: I aggree with you @shekhar, but doing this can be little bit tricky for a novice in .net form environment. setting the level value and then registering the script to hide the label is straight forward method requiring the least changes in this scenario.

Comment: @Shekhar I tried your code but not working for me .. The label not getting hidden..

Comment: @Shekhar It is working fine..Thanks. I had a bad version of jquery which was the reason.

Comment: @Shekhar Can you please tell me how can i call this function from code behind? thanks in advance .

Comment: @Shekhar Also i am using update panel so there is no full page postback to trigger document.ready. Is there any other alternative.? plz help me..